# Manual simulation of Markov Chain in R (2)

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo, markov-chains

> Consider the Markov chain with state space *S = {1, 2}*, transition matrix
>
> [image]
>
> and initial distribution *α = (1/2, 1/2)*.
>
> 1. Simulate 5 steps of the Markov chain (that is, simulate *X<sub>0</sub>*, *X<sub>1</sub>*, . . . , *X<sub>5</sub>*). Repeat the simulation 100 times.

**My solution:**

```
states <- c(1, 2)
alpha <- c(1, 1)/2
mat <- matrix(c(1/2, 1/2, 0, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2) 

nextX <- function(X, pMat)
{
    probVec <- vector()

    if(X == states[1])
    {
        probVec <- pMat[1,]
    }
    if(X==states[2])
    {
        probVec <- pMat[2,]
    }

    return(sample(states, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=probVec))
}

steps <- function(alpha1, mat1, n1)
{
    X0 <- sample(states, 1, replace=TRUE, prob=alpha1)

    if(n1 <=0)
    {
        return (X0)
    }
    else
    {
        vec <- vector(mode="numeric", length=n1)

        for (i in 1:n1) 
        {
            X <- nextX(X0, mat1)
            vec[i] <- X
        }

        return (vec)
    }
}

# steps(alpha1=alpha, mat1=mat, n1=5)

simulate <- function(alpha1, mat1, n1)
{
    for (i in 1:n1) 
    {
        vec <- steps(alpha1, mat1, 5)
        print(vec)
    }
}

simulate(alpha, mat, 100)
```

**Output**

```
> simulate(alpha, mat, 100)
[1] 1 2 2 2 2
[1] 2 1 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
[1] 2 1 1 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 1 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 1 1 2
[1] 2 2 1 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 2 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 2 1 2 2
[1] 2 2 2 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 2 2 1
[1] 1 2 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 2 2 2
[1] 1 2 2 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 1 2 2
[1] 2 2 2 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 2 2
[1] 1 2 1 1 2
[1] 2 2 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 2 2 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 2 2 2 2
[1] 2 1 1 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 2 1 2 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 2 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 2 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 1 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 1 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 2 1 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 1 2 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 2 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 2 1 2
[1] 2 2 2 1 1
[1] 1 1 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 2 1 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 1 2 2
[1] 2 2 1 2 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 2 1 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 1 2 1
[1] 2 2 2 2 1
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 2 1 1
[1] 2 2 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 1 2 2 1
[1] 2 2 1 1 1
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
[1] 2 2 1 2 2
[1] 2 1 2 2 2
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
```

As you can see, I am getting same output in each iteration.

How can I fix my code?

Comment: You aren't getting the same output for each iteration. I'm not sure why you think that. But you shouldn't ever see a switch from a 2 to a 1 with that transition matrix.

Comment: @Dason, kindly explain more in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues:

### Transposed Matrix

If you check the matrix you have input, it is the transpose of what you wanted:

```
> mat
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.5    0
[2,]  0.5    1
```

So, change that.

### States are not Chained

In the `step` function, the returned state is not used to initiate the subsequent state. Instead, `X0` just keeps getting passed in repeatedly:

```
for (i in 1:n1) 
{
    X <- nextX(X0, mat1)
    vec[i] <- X
}
```

Honestly, you don't need `X0` at all. Just change all the `X0`s in the `step` function to `X` and it should work.

Comment: @user366312 it is in the right form, and has all the essential parts, but just wasn't connected together correctly. Having the chaining though is a core concept of the Markov chain, so if it was getting graded you might take a significant deduction for not having that correct.